# Moq: How to Setup ToDictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want to mock a Linq expression that returns a Dictionary<string, string>

```
Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "Service", "serviceTest" }
}
```

```
equipment.SetProperties(dmsElement.Properties.ToDictionary(x => x.Definition.Name, x => x.Value));
```

Here is the unit test

```
fakeEquipment.Setup(e => e.Properties.ToDictionary(It.IsAny<Func<IDmsElementProperty, string>>(), It.IsAny<Func<IDmsElementProperty, string>>())).Returns(properties);
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: ... => ....ToDictionary<IDmsElementProperty, string, string>(It.IsAny<Func<IDmsElementProperty, string>>(), It.IsAny<Func<IDmsElementProperty, string>>())

How can I setup the *ToDictionary* method to retrieve the expected values?

Comment: You don't. You can't mock utility methods like that

Comment: Why not mocking and setting up the field `dmsElement.Properties`?

Comment: It's an Interface `IPropertyCollection<IDmsElementProperty, IDmsElementPropertyDefinition> Properties { get; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mock the `ToDictionary` method because it is an extension method found in the `System.Enumerable` type. That method is going to enumerate your `.Properties` property no matter what.
You can and should, however, mock directly `e.Properties`.
You can return an implementation of the `IPropertyCollection` interface, or if it's not that much of a problem write a very simple adapter exposing an underlying collection (be it a dictionary or a list).
If you have access to an existing class (say, `ListPropertyCollection<T>`), you could just instantiate it.